# Prove that if $A \mathbf x = \mathbf 0$ has a unique solution then $A$ is left invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf}$
Prove that if $A \b x = \b 0$ has a unique solution then $A$ is left invertible. $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix.

Let $A_{re}$ be row reduced echelon form of $A$.

Since $A \b x = \b 0$ has a unique solution therefore $A_{re}$ has a pivot in every column. By definition of row reduced echelon form, the first $m$ rows of $A_{re}$ has pivot and rest of the rows are zero rows.

Let $\b a_1 = (\alpha_1, ..., 0),\b a_2 = (0, \alpha_2, ..., 0), ..., \b a_m = (0, ..., \alpha_m)$ be the rows of $A_{re}$ and let $B_{m \times n}$ be a matrix with columns $\b b_1, ..., \b b_n$.

$$BA_{re} = \b {b_1 a_1} +\b{ b_2 a_2} + ... + \b{ b_n a_n}  = \b {b_1 a_1} +\b{ b_2 a_2} + ... + \b{ b_m a_m},$$

Since $\b a_k = (0, ..., \alpha_k,  ... ,0)$, therefore $\b {b_k a_k} = \begin{bmatrix} \b 0 & ... & \b b_k \alpha_k & ... & \b 0  \end{bmatrix}$.

If we define $\b b_k := \left(0, ... , \dfrac1\alpha_k, ... , 0 \right)^T$ for $0 <k \le m $, then $\b {b_k a_k} = \begin{bmatrix} \b 0 & ... & \b I_k & ... & \b 0  \end{bmatrix}$, where $\b I_k$ is the kth column of $I_{m \times m}$.

Hence we get $B A_{re} = \begin{bmatrix} \b I_1 & ... & \b I_k & ... & \b I_m  \end{bmatrix} = I_{m \times m}$

Since $A_{re} = EA$, $I = BA_{re} = BEA = (BE) A$.

Therefore $A$ is left invertible. $\Box$

Is this proof correct ? I have bit of doubt in the part where I define columns of $B$ so that $B$ becomes left inverse of $A$.

Comment: This seems like it's easier to prove by contraposition, i.e. if $A$ does not have a left inverse, then $Ax = 0$ has more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct.

Another way, $A = [columns] = [ A_1 A_2 ...A_n]$ and $\b {x} = [x_1 x_2 ... x_n]^T$

$A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 + ... A_n x_n = 0$

Substituting $[0,0, ...0]$ satisfies above equation. As solution is unique , trivial solution is the only solution. It means columns of A are linearly independent $\implies$ A has inverse

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is $m \times n$, and that $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $

Now, we are given that the system of equations

$ A x = \mathbf{0} $

where $\mathbf{0} \in \mathbf{R}^m $ has only the trivial solution $ x = \mathbf{0} \in \mathbf{R}^n $.  Expand the matrix-vector equation column-wise, you get

$ A_1 x_1 + A_2 x_2 + \dots + A_n x_n = \mathbf{0} $

The fact that only $ x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n = 0 $ is a solution of this vector equation, implies that the columns $A_1, A_2, \dots , A_n$ are linearly independent.  This automatically means that $ m \ge n $.  And this also means that the column rank of $A$ is $n$.  Now, the matrix $A^T A$ is $n \times n$ and is of full rank equal to $n$.  Therefore, its inverse exists.

The left inverse of $A$ is defined as

$ A^{\#} = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T $

Since $A^T A$ is invertible, then the left inverse of $A$ as defined above exists.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the prior answers, and the question itself, address the issue in a very nitty-gritty way.

A cleaner, more abstract way to answer the question is to note that $A$ is a linear map. A linear map has trivial kernel if and only if it is injective. A map is injective if and only if it has a left inverse. Done.